# org2ogr PostgreSQL to GPX

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, gpx

I already have found how to import `GPX` files into `PostgreSQL` using `gdal/org2org`. Now I am wondering of dumping into `GPX` files the results of my modification on dataset stored into `PostgreSQL`. But I have not found how to do so. Provided I have kept the original structure of tables generated by `ogr2org`, how can I dump their contents into a `GPX` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General syntax would be something like this

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx 
PG:"host=myhost user=myloginname dbname=mydbname password=mypassword"
```

The GPX schema only allows certain field names. You can remap field names using the -sql option.

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx 
PG:"host=myhost user=myloginname dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" 
-sql "SELECT field1 AS name, field2 AS desc FROM input"
```

more details here:
http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html

Comment: Just to add, GPX only allows EPSG:4326, and does not know polygons.